# RDLC Report does not show image when i dynamcally add rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, datarow

I initialize  datatable with datarow class. There is an image field. After i initialize the image RDLC report show no image but other column. My RDLC report hold a picturebox control.I set-

```
Image Source=Database
MIMM Type=Image/Bitmap
Value==Fields!Images.Value
```

Here's my code snippet..

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ImageId");
dt.Columns.Add("ImageName");
dt.Columns.Add("Images");
dt.Columns.Add("Barcode");

        DataTable mydata = GetDataSet();
        DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();

        drow["ImageId"] = mydata.Rows[0][0];
        drow["ImageName"] = mydata.Rows[0][1];
        drow["Images"] = mydata.Rows[0][2]; //This is image row
        drow["Barcode"] = mydata.Rows[0][3];
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);

        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

And Here the report viewer code:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
 <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Report1.rdlc">
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I have already change my dataset Image datatype String.Byte[]. But no luck. If I set my datatable without any datarow then image show clearly. I don't know why? I googled it but can't find any perfect solution.  Please Help me.(Sorry for my poor English.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of column "Images" using

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Images");
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //OR the type you want
```

After that add this column to your table